# Overstayed in Ukraine

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, overstaying, ukraine

I overstayed during my last trip. I have a British passport and I should stay 90 days over 180 days. How shall I calculate my date of return?

Comment: This calculator might help https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/content/visa-calculator_en

Comment: If you already returned from your trip with overstay, your next entry will have standard rules applicable: the border check will go back 180 days from the date of the entry and see if you were staying in Ukraine for 90 days during that time period.

Answer (score 3):

If they don't notice the overstay, you should be fine after having been outside Ukraine for 90 days or more.  If they do notice the overstay, you might need to stay away for a few years.